# JSON objects within pandas series

Tags: python

I have a pandas series with list of JSON objects in string format as values. Below is an example.

```
sr = pd.Series(['[{"fruit": "apple", "box_a": 2}, {"fruit": "grape", "box_b": 4}]', '[{"fruit": "orange", "box_g": 2}]', '[{"fruit": "mango", "box_c": 6}, {"fruit": "grape", "box_e": 3}]'])
```

My objective is to find an efficient way to convert this series into a dataframe with the following structure. As a novice, I can only think of doing the transformation using nested loops, where I iterate through each row and item.

```
sr_df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit':['apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'mango', 'grape'], 'box':['box_a', 'box_b', 'box_g', 'box_c', 'box_e'], 'count':[2,4,2,6,3]})
```

I look forward to learning new approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `json` and `itertools.chain` you get something like this:

```
import itertools
import json
import pandas as pd

data_json = ['[{"fruit": "apple", "box_a": 2}, {"fruit": "grape", "box_b": 4}]', '[{"fruit": "orange", "box_g": 2}]', '[{"fruit": "mango", "box_c": 6}, {"fruit": "grape", "box_e": 3}]']
data = (json.loads(i) for i in data_json)
data = itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

> ```
>   box_a   box_b   box_c   box_e   box_g   fruit
> 0 2.0                 apple
> 1     4.0             grape
> 2                 2.0 orange
> 3         6.0         mango
> 4             3.0     grape
> ```

then you can set `fruit` as index and `stack` to get the result

```
result = df.set_index('fruit').stack().astype(int)
```

> ```
> apple box_a   2
> grape box_b   4
> orange    box_g   2
> mango box_c   6
> grape box_e   3
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- first convert strings to python list of dictionaries by [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html)
- in list comprehension create new DataFrame, set column `fruit` to index
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- for integer convert by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)
- convert `MultiIndex` to columns and rename column

---

```
import ast

df = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x).set_index('fruit') for x in sr.apply(ast.literal_eval)])
       .stack()
       .astype(int)
       .reset_index(name='count')
       .rename(columns={'level_1':'box'}))
print (df)
    fruit    box  count
0   apple  box_a      2
1   grape  box_b      4
2  orange  box_g      2
3   mango  box_c      6
4   grape  box_e      3
```